# How to preserve WebView state in Jetpack Compose Navigation?

Tags: android, webview, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-navigation

When using WebViews to display HTML content, and using a new Activity to show a new page, the state of all WebViews is automatically preserved and restored by the OS when a new WebView activity is opened/closed. This leads to an uninterrupted back-navigation user experience.

Having said that, I'm wondering if it's possible to replicate such experience when using [Jetpack Compose Navigation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation) or any of the 3rd party libraries that wrap around it to provide high-level navigation API? If I understand correctly, the issue at hand is that under a single-activity architecture Composables are completely disposed of and recreated. We need to keep the persistent state in a lifecycle aware component, such as ViewModel. Trouble is, I couldn't find a way to do that with a WebView, even with the one provided by the [Accompanist](https://google.github.io/accompanist/webview/) library. The lack of complete state restoration leads to the loss of currently loaded page when navigating back, as well as the scroll position, thus greately hurting the user experience. I tried experiementing with `saveState` and `restoreState` methods of the `WebView` class, to no avail. Hence I would greatly appreciate if someone can show a working example of how one can fully save and restore the state of the WebView upon back-navigation when using the Compose navigation APIs.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. If you were able to solve it please share your experience!!!

Answer (score 0):

Most recently, the Accompanist started providing `rememberSaveableWebViewState`.
Available from Maven version `0.31.1-alpha`.
There is a [link](https://github.com/google/accompanist/pull/1557) about this solution.

Comment: I am also facing the same, what if I dont want to use Accompanist.